# Python3 ValueError - Too many values to unpack while iterating over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror, list-manipulation

This is a simple code meant to generate a list of full names using a list of English first and surnames:

```
names = """
Walter
Dave
Albert""".split()

fullnames = [(first + last) for first, last in names]
print(fullnames)
```

I made `names` smaller just for the sake of this post, but I included 100 names.

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pussyslayer42069/Desktop/py/names.py", line 105, in <module>
    fullnames = [(first + last) for first, last in names]
  File "/home/pussyslayer42069/Desktop/py/names.py", line 105, in <listcomp>
    fullnames = [(first + last) for first, last in names]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: please add the output which you want as it is not clear what you want. Why are you unpacking the list like that??

Comment: assigning "Walter" to `first`, and "Dave" to `last`, "Water Dave". @irfanwani

Comment: Names is a list, so when you iterate over it, there is only one value each time. You are trying to get 2 values - first and last.

Comment: So do you want result as ["Walter Dave", "Dave Albert"] or ["Walter Dave", "Albert (and next name)"].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` and iterate over two slices of the list

`[(f, l) for f, l in zip(names[:-1], names[1:]]`

Answer (score 0):

If i got you, here is the solution;

```
names = """
Walter
Dave
Albert""".split()


fullnames = [(names[i] + ' ' + names[i + 1]) for i in range(len(names) - 1)]
print(fullnames)
```